# Reading input data using Scanner class

Tags: java

I have a doubt on reading input using scanner class. Usually it goes this way.If I use the print instead of println I can get the input in the same line

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter loan amount:   ");
        double loanAmount = sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Now I want to extend the use of scanner in some other way but I am unable to do so.

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        double val = 0.0;
        System.out.println(""Enter a command push n,add");
        Calculator xyz = new Calculator();
        while(true) {
            input = sc.next();
            if(input.equals("push")+val) {
               val = sc.nextDouble();
                xyz.push(val);
                abc.getValues();
            }
            if(input.equals("add"))
            xyz.add();

        }
    }
}
```

In the above I want to read the value in the same line after I type "push"
Eg., When I run the above code I will get o/p as follows

```
Enter a command

push
4
4.0
```

But I want the o/p as:

```
Enter a command

push 4
4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Every line will have exactely one word and one double:

```
System.out.println("Enter a command");
final String command = sc.next();
final double value = sc.nextDouble();
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/mMtldb)

## Option 2

Lines can have commands with a variable number of tokens;
Use `sc.nextLine()` and parse the input manually:

```
final String input = sc.nextLine();
eval(input);
```

Where `eval` is something like:

```
private void eval(String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split("\\s+");
    switch (parts[0]) {
        case "push": {
            final double value = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
            stack.push(value);
            System.out.println(value);
            break;
        }
        case "pop": {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
            break;
        }
        case "add": {
            System.out.println(stack.pop() + stack.pop());
            break;
        }
        case "exit": {
            hasNext = false;
            break;
        }
        default: {
            System.err.println("Invalid command");
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/S6crNU)

This last example demonstrates a simple interpreter accepting sequences such as:

```
push 4
push 8
push 10
add
pop
exit
```

You can also achieve the same with code similar to the first example by:

1. calling `sc.next()` to get the actual command
2. "Interpreting" the command
3. Making a sequence of `sc.next*`calls to receive tokens specific to each command.

But I think that the `sc.nextLine()` is somewhat more manageable, specially if you need to validate input.

Comment: Hi Anthony,I guess I didn't explain the question well. Please see the edited code above

Comment: My first example does exactly that, check out the Working Example above, `push 4` is being read in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter a command");
   while(true){
    String val[]=sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    //System.out.println("push "+val[1]);
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(val[1]));

}
   }
   }
```

Output :-

```
Enter a command
push 4
4.0
push 5
5.0
push 6
6.0
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Your explanation works when we use System.out.println but how can I use the same thing in my above if condition. Sorry for my question but I am still in the learning stages of Java